# Dependency Injection adding multiple references using the same Service with different parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a common View/ViewModel that displays different View/ViewModel within it. I'm trying to implement this using Dependency Injection but am struggling to figure this out.

This is what I need to replace maybe using a Factory Method.

```
        services.AddScoped<ViewModels.Administrator.Editor_Small_ViewModel>(x => new ViewModels.Administrator.Editor_Small_ViewModel(x.GetService<ButtonEditor_ViewModel>()!));
        services.AddScoped<ViewModels.Administrator.Editor_Small_ViewModel>(x => new ViewModels.Administrator.Editor_Small_ViewModel(x.GetService<ProductEditor_ViewModel>()!));
```

So, Editor_Small_ViewModel is the parent VM that will then display ether  ButtonEditor_ViewModel or ProductEditor_ViewModel depending on the user selection (passed in though the Constructor of  Editor_Small_ViewModel).

I have tried using a Factory Method but following the tutorials on Blazor that I found, cant get it to work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible. How can the IoC container know which service to export? How do you know which service to use? You can only export a single service. It's not clear how want to consume those dependencies. *"Editor_Small_ViewModel is the parent VM that will then display ether ButtonEditor_ViewModel or ProductEditor_ViewModel depending on the user selection"* - Then this means the Editor_Small_ViewModel has to decide which dependency to use. In this case you must change the constructor to request a Func<TChildViewModel> in case they share a common base type or a dedicated abstract factory.

Comment: @BionicCode Yeah, that was the issue I was facing, I finally came up with a solution that works. I'm not entirely happy with it, but I can at least use the same Editor_Small_ViewModel (which is simply a container) with different editors now.

Comment: I think you should simply add both dependencies to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a slightly better solution than my first attempt, I created a small Factory Class that takes an enum type to create a new instance of Editor_Small_ViewModel which in turn displays ether ButtonEditor_ViewModel or ProductEditor_ViewModel.

```
public class EditorFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public EditorFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Editor_Small_ViewModel Create(AViewModel parameter) => new Editor_Small_ViewModel(parameter);

    public Editor_Small_ViewModel Create1(EditorType editorType)
    {
        switch (editorType)
        {
            case EditorType.ButtonEditor:
                return new Editor_Small_ViewModel(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ButtonEditor_ViewModel>());
            case EditorType.ProductEditor:
                return new Editor_Small_ViewModel(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProductEditor_ViewModel>());
            default: // need to change this to something else, but it will do for now.
                return new Editor_Small_ViewModel(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ButtonEditor_ViewModel>());
        }
    }
}

public enum EditorType
{
    ButtonEditor,
    ProductEditor
}
```

Add the services.

```
services.AddScoped<ViewModels.Administrator.ButtonEditor_ViewModel>();
services.AddScoped<ViewModels.Administrator.ProductEditor_ViewModel>();
services.AddSingleton<EditorFactory>();
```

To use, get the service.

```
        _EditorFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<EditorFactory>();
```

then when the user presses a button, call the create function of the factory, passing in ButtonEditor_ViewModel or ProductEditor_View

```
Current_ViewModel = _EditorFactory.Create(EditorType.ButtonEditor);
```

Or

```
Current_ViewModel = _EditorFactory.Create(EditorType.ProductEditor);
```

Comment: But this is not dependency injection. This is the Service Locator anti-pattern. You must never pass the IoC container around. That's what you create the factory for: to *inject* it. If you allow your classes to access the container directly, then you don't need any factory. I would also eliminate the enum and the associated switch by introducing dedicated CreateButtomEditorViewModel and CreateProductEditorViewModel methods.

Comment: @BionicCode Would be great to see your example code.